# angular material table with button disabled

Tags: angular-material

i am using angular material with data table

and putting a button in the last column

when the value from the data that we fetch from the database is "Approve"

then the button becomes disabled
how I achieve this

```
<!-- Star Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="star" stickyEnd>
      <th mat-header-cell class="editbut" *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell class="editbut" *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogEdit(element)">Edit</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

I am trying to put some ngclass on the mat-row but the value still undefined
so we cant add the disabled

```
[disabled] = "{disabled:row.status == "Approve"}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right syntax is `[disabled]="some condition"`.

So for your case it should be `[disabled]="row.status == 'Approve'"`

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-disable-button-on-condition)

Comment: thanks bro , im in wrong cause using row instead of element